# Android - change screen orientation and the orientation would be applied to whole system

Tags: android, screen-orientation

setRequestedOrientation can be used to change screen orientation in an activity. The effect would be only applied to the activity. After exiting the activity, screen orientation would be restored. 
Is there any way to change screen orientation and the effect would be applied to Android system such that launcher and other APKs would be presented with the current screen orientation. 
(The device doesn't have any sensor to provide orientation information to Android sensorservice.)

Thanks.

Comment: If this were possible, I'd buy an iPhone in a heartbeat.

Comment: @hamer: Were you able to find the soln? Even I want to have that functionality

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this. Your application cannot alter how the system's `Launcher` app, or any other third-party application, is displayed. Giving developers the ability to do so would destroy the user experience... and some applications don't even support both orientation modes, so it wouldn't make much sense anyway. Sorry.

Comment: I found a solution in a blog which is written in Chinese (http://fecbob.pixnet.net/blog/post/35396114-android%E4%B8%AD%E9%80%9A%E9%81%8E%E6%8C%89%E9%8D%B5%E6%97%8B%E8%BD%89%E8%9E%A2%E5%B9%95). We can modify PhoneWindowManager and WindowManagerService of Android frameworks to trigger screen rotation event by key event. But, as you said, not any other third-party application support screen rotation.

Comment: @hamer oh... I didn't realize that changing the source code was allowed. Do you only want it to work for your device or something? You'd have to create a custom build, so no other devices would be able to recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. There is no method available which can change Android system's orientation.

If you really want to, you will have to make the changes to Android source code itself where you will have to change the kernel too.

You will have to create a method in framework which will change the orientation value desired by you. This method will change the orientation value (I guess kernel handles orientation value using sys file system). Once value is change in the file, kernel will automatically change that device orientation.

Comment: I do think it is possible.An app called 'Set Orientation' (play.google.com/store/apps/…) does exactly that.It presets the screen orientation of the android device.So if the user selects the mode as 'landscape',then all the apps will open in the landscape mode.